# JavaFX Modules are not visible for VM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, virtual-machine

I was using Intellij Idea as my IDE. Since I needed to use css files, I've installed Intellij Ultimate. Now javaFx is not working on both of them.

Thrown exception:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

The VM settings are exacly the same, as in the previous IDE. Suprisingly- if I put only one jar in `--add-modules=""`, the missing jar, shown in the console, is the one present in the instruction above. E.g:

`--module-path="C:\\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls` for the console output shown earlier.

`--module-path="C:\\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\\lib" --add-modules=javafx.swing` for

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.swing not found

The path to `lib` folder of javafx is valid. I don't have any idea why is it not working.

Comment: Edit: now it didn't work on both of IDE.

Comment: I've switched SDK to JDK8 for now. JavaFX works fine, but on JDK11 it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to it. I installed Ultimate 2018.3 version, which requires a path variable. I added a path variable in options and replaced (in VM options) the path with the path variable. And now it works. 
[image: Setting path variable]

Current VM options input looke like:

`--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media,javafx.graphics,javafx.swing,javafx.web`

Comment: It's strange but I get the exception: JFXSpinnerSkin (in unnamed module @0x4ce312c2) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x4ce312c2